# QR code - dexing.DexArchiveMergerException

Tags: java, android, qr-code

I have problem with implementing QR library.

[Errors picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d305S.png)

Here is my code of build.gradle(app) :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
}
```

Problem occurs when i implement 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
Here is my class that implements

```
public class QRActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{

    private ZXingScannerView zXingScannerView;
    TextView txtQRIspis;
    Button btnSkeniraj;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.qr_activity);

        txtQRIspis = findViewById(R.id.txtQRIspis);
        btnSkeniraj = findViewById(R.id.btnSkeniraj);
    }

    public void skeniraj(View view){
        zXingScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(zXingScannerView);
        zXingScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        zXingScannerView.startCamera();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        zXingScannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        txtQRIspis.setText("Skenirano : " + result.getText());
        zXingScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
    }
}
```

I have tried with this but it didnt worked : 
multiDexEnabled true in android - defaultConfig.